Got error zip signature when read XLSX file inside zip file
I read some xlsx files that inside a zip file from multipart file. Here is my code:
for(MultipartFile file: files) {
  if(Objects.requireNonNull(file.getContentType()).contains("application/x-zip-compressed")) {
     ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(file.getInputStream());
     ZipEntry entry;
     while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
       if (entry.getName().endsWith(".xlsx")) {
         XSSFWorkbook newWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(zipInputStream);
         Sheet newSheet = newWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
                         ///read content here
         newWorkbook.close();
     }
   }
   zipInputStream.closeEntry();
   zipInputStream.close();
  }
}

I got error:
java.util.zip.ZipException: Cannot find zip signature within the first 4096 bytes
 at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.readFirstLocalFileHeader(ZipArchiveInputStream.java:1040)
 at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.getNextZipEntry(ZipArchiveInputStream.java:660)
 at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipArchiveInputStream.java:630)
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.java:150)
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:94)
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:157)
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:351)
 at org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:64)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:315)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:289)

I tried to extract zip to temp file or read as bytes stream but I still got same error. Please help me solve it.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Are you certain that the file is indeed a zip file?

Sure. I extract it by 7zip and open xlsx file by Excel

The thing is, 7zip can also open other archive types.  Are you able to hexdump the first seven bytes of that file?
